# Is there a way to ask migrated users to complete their profile?

Tags: users, emails, migrations

I hope to migrate users in the database (using Drupal 7).

How will I handle the fact that they have no password, and will need to create one before accessing their profile?

Password is currently on the Join Form and these migrated users shouldn't have to go through the Join form.

Also - what do you suggest for mass email?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't the users currently have a password?

Comment: This is not part of the data I have in hand - I though of setting the same dummy password for all but someone could easily hack in if they knew what the dummy password was. My issue now is that we are trying to encourage people to log in with the University log in module that doesn't use the default email + password stored in Drupal. I am not sure how to get these migrated users connected to that third party log in module instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of [Mass Password Reset](https://drupal.org/project/mass_pwreset) module.

I had same kind of situation when I made a existing website of D6 into D7 & migrated users from there.